# Open google maps on href element (IOS and Android)

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, google-maps

I want to open google maps by clicking on the element on mobile devices.

```
<a href="geo:50.060915,19.948066"><img src='/img/pin.svg'></a>
```

Here it's my code. It's working on Android devices, but not on Apple's. So here is my question, how to ask for opening maps on both of those devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To open "maps" on an iOS device (or Mac for that matter) you'd use:

http://maps.apple.com/?ll=50.060915,19.948066

I think you'd have to write some javascript to determine platform, and then open one of the two urls.

This would generally look like this:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;
if(isAndroid) {
  window.location = 'geo:50.060915,19.948066';
}
else {
  window.location = 'http://maps.apple.com/?ll=50.060915,19.948066';
}
```

Put that in an onclick handler for the `a` and you're set!

Comment: Thanks!!! I can not give you useful, because my rep is not high enough :(

Comment: Haha it's okay. You can only accept an answer after 15 minutes of posting. Wait a bit ;] http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235